# Saltstack. How to create ssh keys per user per server and exchange it

Tags: salt-stack

How can I create ssh private and public keys for user per server during installation, and then add new created public keys for different users on different servers?

For example:

server 1

- user1 has public key in authorized_keys - server1(user2,user3),server2(user1,user2,user3)
- user2 has public key in authorized_keys - server1(user1,user3),server2(user1,user2,user3)
- user3 has public key in authorized_keys - server1(user1,user2),server2(user1,user2,user3)

server 2

- user1 has public key in authorized_keys - server1(user1,user2,user3),server2(user2,user3)
- user2 has public key in authorized_keys - server1(user1,user2,user3),server2(user1,user3)
- user3 has public key in authorized_keys - server1(user1,user2,user3),server2(user1,user2)

I know how to create the keys( public, private), but how can I exchange these keys between servers, two or more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the documentation you'll find the `ssh_auth.present` state. https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.ssh_auth.html#salt.states.ssh_auth.present

To dynamically populate the authorized keys, I use pillar data as the source of truth. To make sure the user and his or her public keys are on the appropriate servers I'll use a salt state such as this example:

cat /srv/salt/server_users.sls

```
{% set users = pillar.get('server_users') %}

{% for user in users %}

{{ user }}_setup:
  user.present

{{ user }}_sshkey:
  ssh_auth.present:
    - source: salt://pubkeys/{{ user }}.pub
    - user: {{ user }}

{% endfor }}
```

Then I drop all my users' public keys into the `/srv/salt/pubkeys/` directory.

At this point I set up either flat file pillars or an external pillar that will give each server a pillar key of `server_users` whose value is a list of users that I want to have exist on that particular server and have ssh keys deployed.

An example of a flat file pillar would look something like this.

cat /srv/pillar/top.sls

```
base:
  'server01':
    - users.server01
  'server02':
    - users.server02
```

cat /srv/pillar/users/server01.sls

```
server_users:
  - sarah
  - joe
  - kari
  - kanchan
```

cat /srv/pillar/users/server02.sls

```
server_users:
  - kanchan
  - john
  - sumit
```

So in this example kanchan would have access to both servers while the other users would only have access to one of the servers.

Comment: Thank you for reply,
"Then I drop all my users' public keys into the /srv/salt/pubkeys/ directory."
Do you do this manually ?
I try to find ability to exchange public keys between minions through master node, is it possible ?  So, will have all steps automized.

Comment: I have the users give me their public keys ahead of time. Or I generate the keys on the master. Then I'm deploying the public keys from the master.